# How to make full width and height slider(with header menu) to fit every device screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I want to make full width slider(with every slider) with header part to fit every devices screen specially for the large devices.How to make that possible.I searched on net but cant get anything better.So if any one have idea for this pls help me.

Comment: Google! for Responsive Slider! that's all!

Comment: If any prolem, then try here, ask a question more specificely

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrape carousal its goodand provide full with slider and also full page slider..may be u'll get code in bootstrap4
check this http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/